# node.js get file via https results in socket hangup

Tags: node.js, ssl, https, request

I want to GET a file from a url via https and get following error:

> Error: socket hang up

The funny thing is that accessing this file via Browser and curl it is working, but not via node.js (request) and wget.

I have investigated this issue and found out the following:

1. The SSL cert of the server is issued by DigiCert and contains a cert in the chain that is not commonly preinstalled, which is: DigiCert SHA2 High Assurance Server CA. The other cert in the chain is DigiCert High Assurance EV Root CA which should be fine
2. The server also supports a limited amount of TLS Protocols. Only SSL3 (which is insecure and TLS 1.0 are supported)
3. As mentioned above I can GET the file via curl. When using wget it only works if I explicitly set the SSL protocol and supply the ca cert chain file (wget --secure-protocol=TLSv1 --ca-certificate="path/to/ca-chain-file.pem" https://path/to/image.jpg)

Now I tried to accomplish two things but failed:

1. Register the ca-cert with my OS (locally a MAC, the server runs on Ubuntu)
2. Supply these extra configs when making the GET request in my node app:

   ```
   request.get({
       url: location,
       encoding: 'base64',
       agentOptions: {
           ca: fs.readFileSync('path/to/ca-chain-file.pem'),
           secureProtocol: 'TLSv1_method'
       }
   })
   ```

**Please help**